# datomic caching and cache miss

Tags: caching, datomic

In datomic if I am looking for a key which is NOT present in DB, I guess it will always incur cache miss (even if entire DB is cached in peer's memory). So I guess such requests (looking for a non-EXISTING key) will always hit backend DB (network access) and return no result. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of Datomic internals, talking to storage when an element is not found should not be necessary.

Datomic's covering indices are implemented as sorted sets, and the query engine walks these with a binary search. And a binary search is O(log n) as both average and worst case, so you won't take big performance hits by searching for elements that aren't in the DB.

Whether or not the query (peer) has to talk to storage is not related to whether or not the item is present in the database. As the query engine walks the database, any segment that is not present in the peer has to be loaded from storage to the peer.

Comment: What if DB is huge say 10 TB and available cache on peer is only 100 GB in which case entire DB will not fit in cache? Trying to load missing data will lead to evacuation of older data?

Comment: Yeah, there is a LRU cache that tries to keep the working set on the peer but it will swap stuff in and out as needed. However, the amount of swapping stuff in and out does not really change that much depending on whether you search for stuff that exists or stuff that doesn't exist, it's just a general working set problem that applies to any database that can't keep its working set in memory.